# Processing Program To Parse JSON

Tags: json, processing

Is this possible? I am new in programming and dont know what to do. I have researched but cant find anything. I have a json file I want to import than print a key on the screen.

Sorry if this seems stupid, I am new to programming ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi James and welcome to the wonderful world of programming. It is of course possible to read JSON and then print values to screen. It is important to know which language you are working with and if you Google the question I am sure you will find tons of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is way too broad for Stack Overflow, but I'll try to help in a general sense.

Yes, it's possible.

Please take a look at [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/). Do a search for "JSON" and you'll see quite a few results. Read through them.

```
// The following short JSON file called "data.json" is parsed 
// in the code below. It must be in the project's "data" folder.
//
// {
//   "id": 0,
//   "species": "Panthera leo",
//   "name": "Lion"
// }

JSONObject json;

void setup() {

  json = loadJSONObject("data.json");

  int id = json.getInt("id");
  String species = json.getString("species");
  String name = json.getString("name");

  println(id + ", " + species + ", " + name);
}

// Sketch prints:
// 0, Panthera leo, Lion
```

Please try something out, write some code, and post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck.